# map specifc virtual address to a specific physical one

Tags: linux, memory, kernel, memory-address

I am writing a Linux kernel module that needs to map a specific physical address to a specific virtual one, and I just can't find a way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

OK, This is my current solution. To map `phys_addr` to `virt_addr` I use this code:

```
page = pfn_to_page(virt_addr >> PAGE_SHIFT);
pte = get_locked_pte(&init_mm, phys_addr, &ptl);
set_pte_at(&init_mm, phys_addr, pte, mk_pte(page, VM_READ | VM_WRITE | VM_EXEC));
spin_unlock(ptl);
flush_tlb_all();
```

Some explenations: I use the `pfn_to_page` func to get the page struct corresponding to my `virt_addr`. I get the page table entry (`pte`) with the `get_locked_pte` func which needs the physical address corresponding to the wanted `pte` and an uninitalized spinlock (`ptl`). Then, I actually map the page using `set_pte_at` func and the `mk_pte` macro, unlock the spinlock and flush the tlb cache.

This solution seems to work pretty well, though it does not survive a context switch.

Answer (score 0):

Could you tell us the kernel version and CPU architecture/type you are using? Generally speaking, if the specific virtual address you want to mapping to does not overlap with kernel virtual address(such as 0xC0000000), and also if the physical address which your device is using does not overlap with system memory physical address range, you can using the low-level functions(if there is not, you can using assemble language to set up MMU TLB entries directly during kernel booting up) to set up MMU TLB entries to map the specific address to a specific virtual one during kernel booting up. I can provide one example based on 2.6.10 kernel version and Freescale PowerPC CPU, there is a function io_block_mapping to do the thing you want.

Comment: I use kernel 3.0 with the ARM/omap arch. 

I do hook on the kernel boot time (with "pure_initcall" macro) to reserve this physical address using memblock_remove function, so I know that it is free.